# What is the best way to do simultaneous file access on AS400?

Tags: file, batch-file, ibm-midrange

I am trying to write a program which will be run in batch on AS400. This program is going to write a record into a file to reflect its processing status, say, when it is just submitted it adds a record saying it is currently running, and when it is done it updates the same record saying it has finished. If I want to submit this program into batch for multiple times, what is the best way to cope with this type of simultaneous file access to increase the efficiency? I don't want a job to lock the whole file and stops others from updating it in the same time. It can lock the record it needs and leave the rest to others. How to achieve this? RPGLE or QMQRY? Or any other methods?

Answer (score 4):

RPG will not lock the entire file, only the record.

Comment: I would add a provision that it only locks records when the file is opened for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd recommend SQL for (pretty much) *all* file access, even through RPG.  IBM hasn't been updating their Native I/O for a while, just concentrating on the SQL side of things.

Because, during normal use, record locks in RPG are released once the write or update has been performed, you should probably just have your SQL run `WITH NC` (no commit).  You need a way to tie a processing job with the data it's processing *anyways* (assuming stuff is long-running enough that things are in files outside of `QTEMP`) - you want to be able to pick up where you left off, if your job dies (so, you can't rely on holding the lock as a control mechanism).  So don't forget that you're going to need some sort of monitor job (that can at least report the status, if not resubmit things -  look at the `QUSRJOBI` API).

If you're doing this because you're using all Native I/O, and processing huge sets of data (not huge, processor intensive calculations), consider re-writing everything to SQL.  Seriously.  You can get way better performance - we've taken a process that used to run for 25+ hours, to something that runs in 2.5ish.

Comment: Some would disagree with this answer. Though I tend to do more SQL just so I only work the subset of data that I want to work with.

Comment: While the SQE (SQL Query Engine) is getting more attention than the CQE (Classic Query Engine), when using RPG, it's almost always going to be faster to use native IO (which uses the CQE) for single record updates.

Comment: @david - Granted.  But the single-record speed isn't an issue here, regardless.  If he's doing large data-set bound processing (which should be processed through SQL regardless), the difference in single-record speed is immaterial compared to the execution time of the rest of the program.  Unless you're hitting multiple dozens (or possibly hundreds) of files for single, largely un-related records, it's not likely to be a significant gain.  SQL is also _likely_ to help coach thinking about the data as sets, and not records; relying on native I/O record concepts gives SQL problems later.

Comment: @X-Zero the biggest risk with SQL is to think it's the silver bullet.  SQL is very useful (although annoying to debug) ... but the old saying "Use the right tool for the right job" is as relevant today as it was yesterday.

From what I picked up in the OP question, a single record was going to be read, locked for update, modified, and committed.  In this case, RLA is probably more efficient than SQL.

Comment: @david eh, sorry, what is RLA? And, I want a record to be written to that file first before any further manipulation. So is it possible to do a write operation without locking the entire file?

Comment: RLA == Record Level Access.

As for file locking ... absolutely ... a system would be totally useless if it did an exclusive lock on a file just to write a record.

Note: A file will be _locked_ ... but it will be a non-exclusive lock... so other processes will be able to access and update it.

Comment: @david so how to achieve this record level access? Using RPGLE?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder sorry, RLA is a fancy way of saying "Native file access" in RPG ... read, chain, write, update, etc.